# JQuery post, Spring Boot returns bad content type

Tags: jquery, spring

I'm attempting a simple post request to my Spring Boot server using EasyUI.

The request is simple as:

```
$.post('/company/delete', {
        id:row.id
    }, function(result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $('#dg').datagrid('reload'); // reload the user data
        } else {
            $.messager.show({ // show error message
                title : 'Error',
                msg : result.msg
            });
        }
    }, 'json');
```

And the server side:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public int delete(@RequestBody List<Company> JSONString){
    System.out.println("print json  "+JSONString);
    int userinfo = companyService.deleteByPrimaryKey(JSONString);
    return userinfo;
}
```

Although I post json data to server, the server returns bad content type:

```
Controller [com.supplyplatform.controller.CompanyController]
Method [public int com.supplyplatform.controller.CompanyController.delete(java.util.List<com.supplyplatform.pojo.Company>)]

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@RequestBody` in the `delete` method.